# Customizing equals method as per the use case

Tags: java

I have a class defined as

```
   class Book{
        String author;
        String title;
        int id;
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            return id == ((Book)o).id;
        }
        public int hashCode{...}
   }
```

In most of the cases uniqueness of the Books is determined by `id`, hence works properly. In one particular case, I want to merge two lists based on `author` and `title` value. I cannot directly use a `Set` and add the second list to the Set as comparison will happen on ids and not on author/title value. Only way for me is to have two nested `for` loops to compare each object's value.

```
List<Book> list1=...;
    List<Book> list2 = ...;

    Iterator<Book> iterator = list1.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Book b1 = iterator.next();
        for(Book b2:list2){
            if(b1.getAuthor().equals(b2.getAuthor()) && b1.getTitle().equals(b2.getTitle())){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    list2.addAll(list1);
```

Is there any way where we can override the equals method as per the use case (similar to `Comparator` where we can change the sort algorithm)?

Instead just have customized equals method that will check the author value and somehow following works

```
set.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: I am assuming you don't want the books to be considered equal by author and title except in this particular use case? Would it really be that bad to consider a book the same if author and title are the same in all cases? I think it depends on your design.

Comment: Your equals() is fine as it is. It will be a bad design to modify it just for a certain lazy call set.addAll().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly, you can use a TreeSet with a custom comparator:

```
TreeSet<Book> set = new TreeSet<Book>(new Comparator<Book>() {
  public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
    int r = o1.author.compareTo(o2.author);
    if (r != 0)
      return r;
    return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
  }      
});

set.add(...);
```

SortedSet guarantees uniqueness, but it doesn't make use of equals() or hashcode(). Instead, it uses the comparator (or natural ordering) for determining equality.

Comment: ah.. I didn't know about it. But seems riskier as the contract is not followed

Comment: @sidgate: The contract problem has no effect here: you may have values in the set which are "equal" according to the equals() method (which is against the contract of a Set). However, the set is guaranteed to distinguish between items according to author+name only.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something liek that with closures, but it is not overriding as such.  The problem you have is this is a O(N*M) time complexity which is not idea.  A better approach is O(N) is

```
Map<String, Book> books = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Book book : list1) books.put(book.author+"/"+book.title, book);
for (Book book : list2) books.remove(book.author+"/"+book.title);
list2.addAll(books.values());
```

---

For closures, you need a few functions I couldn't find.

```
static class MapStream<K, V> {
    final Map<K, V> map;
    final Function<V, K> func;

    MapStream(Iterable<V> values, Function<V, K> func) {
        map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.func = func;
        addAll(values);
    }

    private void addAll(Iterable<V> values) {
        for (V value : values)
            map.put(func.apply(value), value);
    }

    public MapStream<K, V> removeAll(Iterable<V> values) {
        for (V value : values) {
            map.remove(func.apply(value));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        return map.values();
    }
}


public static <T> Function<T, String> and(Function<T, String> func1, Function<T, String> func2) {
    return (T t) -> func1.apply(t) + "\uffff" + func2.apply(t);
}


public static void main(String... ignored) {
    List<Book> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Book> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Function<Book, String> commonKey = and((Book b) -> b.author, (Book b) -> b.title);
    list2.addAll(new MapStream<>(list1, commonKey).removeAll(list2).values());
}
```

You can see that with some support you can see something with closures.

Comment: This looks good from performance perspective. You mentioned that it can be done with closures. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 2):

In general you need to externalize `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Therefore you could have something like:

```
class MyModelClass {

    private EqualsImpl<MyModelClass> equalsImpl;

    public MyModelClass(EqualsImpl<MyModelClass> equalsImpl) {
        super();
        this.equalsImpl = equalsImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return equalsImpl.equals(this, obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return equalsImpl.hashCode(this);
    }

}

interface EqualsImpl<C> {

    public boolean equals(C obj1, Object obj2);

    public int hashCode(C obj);

}
```

Comment: Novel, but it means you have to specify a single use case for the object when you construct it.

Comment: good idea, and might be useful in some scenarios, but in my case I cannot decide the implementation at object creation time. Also, it would be required to set it to all objects everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Book {

    String author;
    String title;
    int id;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return id == ((Book) o).id;
    }

    //getters and setters
    //other methods

}

class BookComparator implements Comparator<Book>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
        if(o1.getAuthor() == o2.getAuthor() && o1.getTitle() == o2.getTitle())
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

}
```

and then you can do something like

```
Set<Book> lSet = new TreeSet<Book>(new BookComparator());
lSet.addAll(list1);
lSet.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but I think maybe it was because you showed an example of a `Comparator` when the OP specified that they were looking for something 'similar' to a `Comparator`, and therefore not an actual `Comparator`.

Comment: OMG!! How will it compile. You need to have getters and setters in the class. It's just a solution to OPs problem.

Comment: @AniketThakur: no, I was referring to the compare method. Not all execution paths return a value...

Comment: Ohh I get your point now. You can return 1 as it does not matter. We are only concerned about elements with same title and author and not about the order.

Comment: @AniketThakur: Now it compiles, but it has a bug and doesn't guarantee uniqueness. You are breaking the contract of compare(..), making the order relation inconsistent. This results in the balanced search tree failing to place items correctly, and creating duplicates. Try it.

Comment: -1: The compare method should return -1, 0, or 1 for a<b, a=b and a>b respectively. You can see a possible implementation in my answer. As I mentioned, your current implementation won't work correctly with TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `List` which decorates the `List.add()` (or `List.addAll()`) using a `Comparator` like the `TreeSet`

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to answer of @Aniket Thakur (+1).

Yes, I also recommend you to use `Comparator`. You should define `Comparator` per your use case and use collections that work with comparators, e.g. `TreeSet`, `TreeMap`. This is the clearest way to achieve what you need: separation of comparison logic from model class itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    return (author.equals(((Book)o).author) && title.equals(((Book)o).title));
}
```

why can't you override the equals method as above.

Comment: because in most of the cases id is used for uniqueness. I cannot change the equals method behaviour just for one use case

Comment: @sidgate - Couldn't you just have equals() return true if the id matches OR the title and author are the same?